# Showing that an $\mathbb{R}$-action is proper

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, group-actions

Let $\mathbb{R}$ act freely and smoothly on a manifold $M$, such that the space of orbits $M/\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth manifold and the projection $M \to M/\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth submersion.

Is it then true that the $\mathbb{R}$-action is proper? I suspect that it is, but have trouble explicitly showing it. Any advice?

I see that this is some kind of converse statement to the Quotient Manifold Theorem, however that didn't help me so far.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/converse-to-quotient-manifold-theorem-exercise-in-lee-smooth-manifolds

Comment: Thank you, that would be a way to do it. I am just wondering if for this simple example $G=\mathbb{R}$ there is a direct way, without first proving that $M$ is a principal bundle.

Comment: I am not at all convinced that the argument in the link is a valid proof. Details are missing.

Comment: I wrote details for the linked answer. You can avoid using the terminology "principal fiber bundle" but, even in the case when $G={\mathbb R}$, the proof will go through the same steps.

Comment: Thank you very much!